# Node.js BinaryServer: Send a message to the client on stream end?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a node.js BinaryServer for streaming binary data and I want a callback event from the server, after the client calls for the `.Stream.end()` function.

I can't seem to understand - How can I send a message or some kind of notification when the node.js server actually closes the stream connection ?

**Node JS:**

```
server.on('connection', function(client) {

    client.on('stream', function (stream, meta) {

        stream.on('end', function () {
            fileWriter.end();
            // <--- I want to send an event to the client here
        });
    });

});
```

**client JS:**

```
client = new BinaryClient(nodeURL);
window.Stream = client.createStream({ metaData });
....
window.Stream.end();
//  <--- I want to recieve the callback message
```

Comment: On the Node JS side, you can try `client.send("finished")`

Comment: @ExplosionPills And what should I do on the client side ?

Comment: Listen to the `stream` event, `client.on("stream", data => /* do something with data */)`

Comment: @ExplosionPills Sorry, didn't get it, can you explain the code precicely on the client and on the server side ?

Comment: According to [documentation](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/blob/master/doc/api.md#event-end) `.end()` appears to expect a function as parameter _"Is emitted when `stream.end` has been called. `stream.readable` is set to false."_ `window.Stream.end(function() {// stream ended});`

Answer (score 1):

On the server side, you can send streams to the client with `.send`. You can send a variety of data types, but a simple string will probably suffice in this case.

On the client side you can also listen to the `'stream'` event to receive data back from the server.

**Node JS:**

```
server.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.on('stream', function (stream, meta) {
        stream.on('end', function () {
            fileWriter.end();
            client.send('finished');
        });
    });    
});
```

**client JS:**

```
client = new BinaryClient(nodeURL);
client.on('stream', data => {
    console.log(data); // do something with data
});
window.Stream = client.createStream({ metaData });
....
window.Stream.end();
```

Comment: I added the code you suggested, but `client.on('stream', data =>` is never triggered.